# Are they really the virtual codes?

Tags: java, c++, c, keycode

Virtual key codes for some keys like *shift, [ , ],Del etc* are displayed as a different value in java compared to C++/C. For example :

```
Key     Java       C / C++
Shift   16         160
[       91         219
]       93         221
\       92         220
Del     127        46
Window  524        91
```

**What is the reason for this ?** Are these codes the virtual codes or they are a different type ? For the keys including alphabets,numbers,the function keys(F1-F12),backspace,`,etc are the same.

*I might be misunderstanding a concept,in that case please clarify.*

*Checked in C/C++*

```
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT * kbhook = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
printf("%u\n",kbhook->vkCode);
```

*Checked in Java*

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    int code = evt.getKeyCode();
    // code isEqualTo KeyEvent.VK_DELETE : NOTE

}
```

Ref : [KeyEvent class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: For `[`, `]`, `\\` and Del, those Java codes are the ASCII values of those keys. Why should they be virtual? The result you get from the Windows hook function seems to be scancodes.

Comment: Those aren't C/C++ codes, those are WinAPI codes. They're not used for either C or C++ on other platforms, and other WinAPI-based applications (built with Delphi, for example) use the same codes.

Comment: Does it matter if they are the same or not? They are used to identify certain keys (by comparing them to constants - for instance `KeyEvent.VK_X` in java). The only thing I can think of, where this would be a problem, is if a Java application communicates with a C++ application somehow by forwarding key events. Then you would either have to parse the codes to a unified code or translate them to the other system before forwarding them.

Comment: @brimborium yes, i want a communication b/w c++->java

Comment: From the hook callback function, call [ToAscii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or possibly [ToUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to turn the virtual key code into something Java understands.

Comment: @SuhailGupta I see. Then I would suggest you create a parser in C++: `int getJavaKeyCode(int cppKeyCode);` if you really need the keycodes to be forwarded (and for instance a `char` is not sufficient).

Comment: @brimborium and in that parser should i map the c++ keys to java keys,by writing each key first ? A tedious task !

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg then what does `KeyEvent.VK_DELETE = 127 = ke.getKeyCode()` _(on pressing delete key)_ mean ? `VK_DELETE` is the virtual code for delete key. Isn't it ? Did you look at         [virtual codes here](docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: @SuhailGupta Yes, very tedious, you would have to fill some sort of (hash)map in the initialization. The other method would be to find some other identification for the keys instead of those codes (or find a way in JAva to gather the keys from the Windows API VK's).

Comment: What do you get if you modify the C++ code to call ToUnicode() and the Java version to call KeyEvent.getKeyChar()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Key Codes are extremely virtual, I should say.

You won't get away without some code like JavaKeyToWin32Key, Win32KeyToJava and so on for each platform you're trying to interoperate with.

I believe all of these keycodes are mostly historical. Some come from hardware design decisions (take a look at Apple's "modern" key codes where the 0 code is 'A', 1 is 'S', 2 is 'D' and so on - should I continue or you get the "pattern" which follows from the keyboard layout ?).

"Why there are no standard ?"

It's business and nothing personal. Thirty-forty years ago everyone where developing their own hardware from scratch, twenty five years ago everybody were trying to make the best CPU, 15 years ago it has all began with the "platforms", where everything was once again redefined, but also should maintain compatibility with existing solutions (by the same company, of course).

Java is a standard, but not for everyone. It is already an abstraction above all the OSes with its own set of keycodes. So "VK_" is a legacy of Microsoft, Java key codes might be influenced by the Sun Solaris OS, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Someone would have to coordinate the standard and everything would suddenly get complicated. Different systems have different keyboards and therefore codes (have a look at the keyboard from an old Sun machine) and creating a single standard to handle them all would be unnecessarily complex. Plus, it would only matter for a few rare cases, usually if you write an app for PC you don't have to and don't want to care about handling key codes from some rare enterprise machine from the 1970's.

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are a MS specific representation of certain keys found on a typical keyboard. Hence the *virtual* modifier. Note, the values that you have specified for Java represent the values of those keys when using the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding. They form part of the [lower ASCII](http://www.tntbasic.com/learn/help/guides/asciicodesexplained.htm) encoding. If OTOH, you used a standard C function such as `getchar` you'd get the same values as in Java provided you are using the ASCII encoding. You could however have a special (think non-ASCII/non-Unicode) encoding where these characters will be assigned different integers.

The ASCII set particularly is carefully designed keeping in mind that certain oft-used operations (such as lowercase to uppercase) etc. can be optimized.

Comment: i want a c++ snippet to communicate with java application. How can i know which key was pressed when the codes are different ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta By either picking one of them as the new norm, and translate to/from as needed, or inventing your own mapping and translating to/from that. This, of course, assumes you own both the C++ and Java code.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Library says about [Using Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927175.aspx): *"Each key on the keyboard generates a scan code when the key is pressed and released. The scan code is a hardware-dependent number that identifies the key. The keyboard driver translates or maps each scan code to a virtual-key code. The virtual-key code is a hardware-independent number that identifies the key. Because keyboard layouts vary from language to language, Windows CE offers only the core set of virtual-key codes that are found on all keyboards. This core set includes English characters, numbers, and a few critical keys, such as the function and arrow keys"*.

Here's the set of [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx) - these are the values you retrieve from `vkCode` member of [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: i want a c++ snippet to communicate with java application. How can i know which key was pressed when the codes are different ?

Answer (score 0):

yes,in both the cases they are the virtual codes.

Comment: will you also explain the reason,as to why are they different then ?

Comment: "Virtual key code" typically refers to a Microsoft term used only in the Windows API. The Java language knows nothing about that, so I wouldn't call the Java values for virtual key codes.

Comment: @Lundin then what does the static term in [`KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_DELETE) class `VK_DELETE` mean ? I think it surely means the virtual key code for the `Delete` key.

Comment: @SuhailGupta It certainly looks like the Windows virtual key code. But it has a different value? If so, you better ask whoever designed that Java class what they were smoking...

Comment: @Lundin it is different. For example _Windows virtual key code_ in `java` is 524 and through `winapi` is 91