# Example for scancode vs virtual scancode vs keycode vs virtual keycode vs virtual key

Tags: keyboard, virtual, keycode, scancodes

I have problems figuring out the the difference between scancode, virtual scancode, keycode, virtual keycode, virtual key:

- I know that virtual Key (or virtual keycode ??) is a pressed modifier
  (Ctrl, alt, shift)
- I know that scancode (or virtual scancode ??) is a number associated
  with the position on the keyboard which is the same for all keyboards
- What`s the name of the actual printed character on the screen ( e.g. the
  german special character ö ) ?

I find those names used differently on posts on the internet.

Can anyone please provide an example e.g.: **What are those codes for the letter *e* and the letter *E***

- scancode:
- virtual scancode:
- keycode:
- virtual keycode:
- virtual key:

**What I mean is this: For example for the letter e there are 2 numbers: 65 and 18.**

```
 - 65 is the unicode number. Is this number *called* scancode, virtual scancode, keycode, virtual keycode or  virtual key?

 - 18 is the position on the physical keyboard. Is this number *called* scancode, virtual scancode, keycode, virtual keycode or  virtual key?

 - Then I have the Shift-Key. Is this number produced by this key *called* scancode, virtual scancode, keycode, virtual keycode or  virtual key?
```

Comment: There isn't a single answer, as some of these depend on the keyboard layout and language. There is no such thing as "position on all keyboards": consider 102-key keyboard vs one-handed chordal keyboard.

Comment: As for _name_ of a character, not quite sure what you're looking for. Perhaps the most useful source of "character" names is the [Unicode standard](https://home.unicode.org). For example, " ö" would be: "LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS".  Some keys don't necessarily produce characters (but there are sometimes characters that exist that represent these keys, but typing the key doesn't produce that character.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739278/difference-between-virtual-code-and-scan-code